# Array of json string to array of struct in golang?

Tags: go, goland, golang-migrate

I have the following json string array

```
data := []string{
    `{"STATUS":"UP"}`,
    `{"STATUS":"UP"}`,
}
```

and the following struct corresponding to it

```
type Status struct {
    STATUS string `json:"STATUS"`
}
```

How do I unmarshal data into an array of Status struct ?

Comment: This is two questions. 1: how do I turn JSON into a struct, and 2: how do I map over an array.

Comment: Yes. I understand we can loop over slice and unmarshal it one by one. But is there a one liner which does it ?

Comment: If your array was itself JSON: yes (unmarshall would be all you need), but this is an array of strings, you're not going to do anything to those strings without iterating the array _somewhere_

Comment: You appear to have edited one question into a completely unrelated new question. Please *do not do that*.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a one-liner, here it is.

```
var dest []Status
_ = json.Unmarshal([]byte("[" + strings.Join(data, ",")+ "]"), &dest)
```

[Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/pDs9iB338Uh)